# Correct set of dependencies for using Jackson mapper

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am new to Jackson and I was writing some code for practice. I found out that the new version of Jackson library can be found on Fasterxml: [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome), so I added the below dependencies to my Maven POM-file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I was expecting that I can use the `ObjectMapper` directly, however after spending a lot of time I found out that to use the `ObjectMapper` I have to add the old libraries below:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I am a bit confused. Could someone please tell me why is that?

Comment: Do you have issues with package names? As far as i see com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper is part of jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar

Comment: The problem is that as soon as I remove the last two dependencies. I cannot compile my code because of ObjectMapper. what do u mean by "package names" ? thx

Comment: For me this looks like you code is using org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper instead of com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper and because of this could not find class and could not compile.

Comment: Could you show to us problematic code?

Answer (score 62):

```xml
<properties>
  <!-- Use the latest version whenever possible. -->
  <jackson.version>2.4.4</jackson.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

you have a ObjectMapper (from Jackson Databind package) handy.
if so, you can do:

```java
JsonFactory factory = objectMapper.getFactory();
```

Source: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core

So, the 3 "fasterxml" dependencies which you already have in u'r pom are enough for ObjectMapper as it includes jackson-databind.

Answer (score 11):

No, you can simply use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`.
Most likely you forgot to fix your `import`-statements, delete all references to codehaus and you're golden.

Answer (score 4):

The package names in Jackson 2.x got changed to `com.fasterxml`[1](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) from `org.codehaus`[2](http://jackson.codehaus.org/). So if you just need ObjectMapper, I think Jackson 1.X can satisfy with your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I spent few hours on this.

Even if I had the right dependency the problem was fixed only after I deleted the com.fasterxml.jackson folder in the .m2 repository under C:\Users\username.m2 and updated the project

Comment: It happens. The problem is that unless we specify an artifact version using [] notation, what specify is a "suggestion". Maven will try to get that version, but will opt for something difference if there's something in your transitive dependencies that require it.

I nuke my .m2 regularly just to avoid these "surprises."

Answer (score 1):

Apart from fixing the imports, do a fresh `maven clean compile -U`. Note the `-U` option, that brings in new dependencies which sometimes the editor has hard time with. Let the compilation fail due to un-imported classes, but at least you have an option to import them after the maven command.

Just doing Maven->Reimport from Intellij did not work for me.