# NoClassDefFoundError of com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper with Maven

Tags: java, maven, jackson, fasterxml

This is a similar question as the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26068128/3697757), which is unfortunately unresolved yet.

> If you want to debug the code, here is the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/hackjutsu/StackOverflow-Maven-Jackson/tree/master).

I got the following `NoClassDefFoundError` for `ObjectMapper` though I have added the related dependency to Mave `pom.xml`.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
    at demo.DemoMain.main(DemoMain.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Here is the source code `DemoMain.java`

```
package demo;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class DemoMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Start");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println("End");
    }
}
```

This is my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>Demo</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <index>true</index>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>demo.DemoMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I compile and run the app by

```
mvn clean install
java -jar target/Demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: Does the `mvn clean install` build success?

Comment: Yes, `mvn clean install` is successful.

Comment: It's too weird! Maven build successful mean that your code is not having any problem. Did you try to build it using an IDE?

Comment: @TuyenNguyen I'm confused too. Here is the source code repository. https://github.com/hackjutsu/StackOverflow-Maven-Jackson

Comment: you should try to using an IDE to build and run your code. I have tested your code, it run fine!

Comment: Thanks for trying:) Yes, I just tried using IntelliJ and it worked fine. But an IDE shouldn't be a prerequisite for a Java application... Is it because I miss some flags when launching the jar?

Comment: I just figure out that `mvn clean install` does not create any .jar file. So what .jar file you are running on?

Comment: En.. Interesting, it should create a jar file `target/Demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`. Anyway, I figure out the issue. The maven plugin I was using doesn't build a fat jar that comes with dependencies. To run the jar with `java -jar`, we can use `maven-assembly-plugin` instead, which bundles the jar with its dependencies. By the way, the reason why an IDE works is because it adds the classpath flag automatically when running the app. Thanks for helping me troubleshoot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43827141/3697757)

---

The default maven plugin doesn't build a fat jar with dependencies.

To build a jar bundled with its dependencies so that we can execute it with `java -jar`, we can use [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html), which packages the jar with the name `xxx-jar-with-dependencies.jar`.

Here is a sample `pom.xml`

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.example.yourMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now you should be able to run your jar with

```
java -jar xxx-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Answer (score 12):

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
<version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: try this dependancy

Comment: You should add an actual explanation in your answer, otherwise, it's just you pasting some code which the poster might not understand.