# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference

Tags: java, maven, jackson

I'm working on my first Java project with maven. I compiled the code but get the following error when trying to execute the jar:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference

I have the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20211205</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I've tried adding jackson-core as a separate dependency but this won't fix the issue.

Comment: I think the `artifactId` should be `jackson-core`

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.13.0#maven

Comment: Are you sure you have all the dependencies available when executing the jar? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43827141/615104 - the exact same might apply to you

Comment: @JanMartiška Thanks for that! Building the jar with the maven-assembly-plugin with the descriptorRefs instead of the maven-jar-plugin has fixed the issue. Im not sure why this worked before and stopped working, but it works now!